# Simplest way to iterate over all GameObject childrens from a script at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

In my `Unity3D` project I got a complex `GameObject` of a truck that his hierarchy looks like this.

```
+ Truck
   +FrontPivotPoint
      +LeftWheel
        Tire
        Rim
        Hindge
      +RightWheel
        Tire
        Rim
        Hindge
    +CenterPivotPoint
      +Body
        Arm
        Screw
        Pin
```

Basically what's happening is I got a lot of complex parenting and I want to go trough every child and add to him a `RigidBody`.
I think it should be something nested but I don't have something in mind.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity3d allows you to easily automate every routine. You may consider to add custom menu item.

```cs
public class MakeRigidBodies : EditorWindow
{
  [MenuItem ("Make rigid bodies %&r")]
  private static void Execute()
  {
    var selectedObject = UnityEditor.Selection.activeObject;
    if( selectedObject && selectedObject is GameObject )
    {
       // for all children of selectedObject
       {
         // add rigid body
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the structure of your game objects is like a tree data structure. Truck as its parent / root node, and the others as its child. So, you must traverse all the objects / nodes in your structure with tree traversing algorithm, the best that I know is Depth-First-Search (DFS) algorithm.

DFS work like nested loop, the main algorithm are:

1. Start from the root node
2. Find its node children
3. Visit the child
4. Back to step 2 until all children is visited

This algorithm can be implemented in Unity3d since `GameObject` stores its child information in transform properties (see http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/416730/get-the-child-gameobject-of-a-parent-and-not-the-t.html). And last, we can add `RigidBody` to the `GameObject` with the `AddComponent()` method (see http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/19466/how-do-i-add-a-rigidbody-in-script.html).

Here is my script to answer your question:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AddRigidBody : MonoBehaviour { 
    private void addRigidBody(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        Rigidbody rigidBody = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        foreach(Transform t in gameObject.transform)
        {
            addRigidBody(t.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Start () {
        addRigidBody (this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

This script attached to the parent / root `GameObject`. The `AddRigidBody()` method is called when this script start (as in `Start()` method), and this method will traverse all child and add a `RigidBody` through it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, and bear with me since it's been a while since I've worked with Unity3D, this could fix it:

```
* Drag your model onto the stage
* Your entire model should now be selected; parent and its underlying children
* Select the option to add a rigidbody and it should add it to all selected objects.
* Make a prefab of the model and you should be done.
```

Once again, don't trust me on this. It's been a while and since I don't have access to Unity3D right now, I am unable to check this method myself.

If it's the code approach you want, try this (C#, methods may vary for Boo or Java):

Getting a child: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/get-child-c.83512/ (see second reply)
Adding a rigidbody: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/19466/how-do-i-add-a-rigidbody-in-script.html

I hope this helps.